# windows phone 10 app rights re-set

Tags: windows-10-mobile

cant seems to find it anywhere and google spams me with useless articles,

I have refused an banking app the right to use mic (why it would want to use mic in first place is beyond me); but after refusal it ceased to work,

If i try to open app it just goes into loading screen and crashes, so i wanted to re-set the rights but i cant find this setting anywhere,

Where is the app right setting?

ps. reinstalling app and restarting device didnt help.

Answer (score -1):

ok, found it through search function in settings, doesnt seems to be connected to any menu, so im closing the question as more users may need it one day

Comment: If you think other people might run into this issue, could you flesh out your answer a little bit e.g. add the search term?